# Clear all rows from Repeater Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to clear all rows from a Repeater?

I've tried:

`RptSeatOrLap.DataSource=Nothing`

But it's not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call `DataBind()` in order to see the effect of new data source being assigned.

```
RptSeatOrLap.DataSource=dtEmptyDataTable;
RptSeatOrLap.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
rpt.DataSource = null;
rpt.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. Mine is VB so I used Nothing instead of null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'use dispose:

```
rpt.Dispose 
rpt.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rpt.Items.Clear()
rpt.DataBind()
```